# Stack arrays along nth dimension with `MPI_Gatherv`

Tags: arrays, fortran, mpi

I am working on a Fortran code parallelized using MPI. I have a set of 5-dimensional arrays defined at each processor:

```
real(DP) :: Qs(5, 5, 1, 1, ncell)
```

where `ncell` is a different number for each processor. I want to collect all the arrays into one array `Qs_glob` defined at processor 0 as:

```
real(DP) :: Qs_glob(5, 5, 1, 1, ncellglob)
```

where `ncellglob` is equal to the sum of all `ncell` values for the different processors. Therefore, I want to stack the `Qs` arrays along the fifth dimension. I think this can be done using `mpi_gatherv`, however, I have struggled to find a worked example on the web. Can anyone help with that?

**Edit:**

The variable `ncell` is only known locally for each processor. However, these variables can be easily sent to processor 0 via `mpi_gather`. The variable `ncellglob` is known by all processors. The total number of processors `nproc` is also known by all processors.

My problem is to figure out the displacement index in the `mpi_gatherv`, so the the arrays end up being stacked along the 5th dimension.

Comment: There are many examples on the net. It should be pretty straght-forward, the n for each process is just the local size of the array. It would be a much better question if you ncluded some attempt and explain your problems with it. We have no idea what you do understand and what not and SO is not a good place to ask for tutorials. To be really useful for you we would have to know what kind of information you store in each process so you need to show much more code. What does each process know about every other process (especially about `ncell`)? How is this information stored?

Comment: @VladimirF OK, I think I figured it out. The displacement index needs to move each time by the sum of the indices along all dimensions. I'll be editing the question and maybe posting my own answer as well.

Comment: I presume you (OP) know what you are doing with those rank-3 arrays pretending to be rank-5 arrays.  An external observer might think the singleton dimensions are just there to make indexing more mind-bending :-)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark haha yeah, they are 5 dimensional, but in this case two dimensions happen to have a size of 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the solution now. Here is how to do it:

```
subroutine gather_arrays()

use vars ! module defining Qs and ncell
use mpi_mod ! module defining nproc and rank

implicit none

! define the global array
real(DP) :: Q_glob(5, 5, 1, 1, ncellglob)

! define arrays containing the size and displacement index for each local array Qs
integer :: ncells(nproc), displacements(nproc), i 

! send array sizes to processor 0
call mpi_gather(ncell, 1, mpi_integer, ncells, 1, mpi_integer, 0, mpi_comm_world, ierr)

! calculate displacement indices
if (rank == 0) then
   displacements(1) = 0
   do i=2, nproc
      displacements(i) = displacements(i-1) + 5*5*1*1*ncells(i-1)
   end do
end if

! finally, gather all arrays in Q_glob
call mpi_gatherv(Qs, 5*5*1*1*ncell, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, Q_glob, 5*5*1*1*ncells, displacements, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, 0, mpi_comm_world, ierr)

end subroutine
```